# How to lock down Firestore collection group queries based on the resource path via Firestore Security Rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am implementing Firestore collection group queries in an app, and I want to make a security rule that locks down access to users who own the resource they are trying to query

The data in Firestore is structured like `users/1234/.../posts/5678`. I would like to extract the path of the resource that is being queried via the collection group, and then pass the extracted userId (`1234` in this case) into my `signedIn()` method, which just checks a userId against a custom token. I know this `signedIn()` method works correctly, because I have other rules that rely on it that are working perfectly.

I've tried the following in my firestore.rules file:

```
// collection groups
match /{path=**}/posts/{post} {
  allow read: if resource['__name__'][0] == "users" && signedIn(resource['__name__'][1])
}
```

AND

```
// collection groups
match /{path=**}/posts/{post} {
  allow read: if path[0] == "users" && signedIn(path[1])
}
```

Unforfunately with either of these approaches I still get a permission denied error when I try to query the `posts` collection group. I can't even find any good way to debug this, because the Simulator in the dashboard doesn't seem to be very useful for collection group queries.

P.S. I know I could add a `userId` field to a `post` document, and then write a rule like this:

```
// collection groups
match /{path=**}/posts/{post} {
  allow read: if signedIn(resource.data.userId)
}
```

and in fact I have tried this and made it work. But for business reasons I would prefer not to do it this way if at all possible.

Comment: I didn't get this to work either, but I'm fairly certain you are using `resource['__name__']` "wrong": from the rules playground I can see that the first three parts are `/databases/%28default%29/documents/`, so if you want `users` then you'd be looking for `resource['__name__'][3]` instead of `[0]`. At first my guess was that for collectionGroup queries you cannot examine the resource, because that would require every single potential hit to be examined - a LOT of reads (the max is currently 20 per security rule check). But if you got it working with `resource.data` then I dunno what's up

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to restrict the user making the db call to only allow them to view posts that belong to the user?

This is what a signedIn method looks like in the firestore rules:

```
function signedIn() {
  return request.auth.uid != null;
}
```

and a way to restrict users to only crud operations within a path that is the same as their uid

```
match /users/{userId}/posts/{postsId} {
  allow create, read, update: if request.auth.uid == userId && signedIn();
}
```

Comment: Correct, that is what I'm trying to do. However there's a wrinkle. I need to use [collection group queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) to query multiple subcollections of `posts`. Unfortunately, this means the method you show above will not work in this case

Comment: @JeffJohnson - Did you ever find a solution to this? I have a similar situation and have come to the conclusion that path-based rules and collection group queries can't be mixed. You can have a data design that uses one or the other, but not both. Thoughts?

Comment: @CliffChaney I ended up doing just adding the `userId` to the document and checking it via the method at the bottom of my original post. It wasn't too difficult for the backend to add that information to the document, so I went with the path of least resistance. I was never able to get anything else working

Comment: That's odd but nowhere in the firebase documentation do they mention how to prevent users from making collection group queries.